# Please suggest any ssh client to install in ubuntu and where to download the same

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-9.04

Please suggest any ssh client to install in ubuntu and where to download the same

Comment: This is not a programming related question.

Comment: You can just [click here](http://www.apturl.net/index.php/install/ssh) to install ssh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install ssh`

Or `openssh-client` if you just want the client.

Answer (score 2):

To install both ssh client and server, open a terminal (Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal) and enter:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

It will ask for your password, and then install OpenSSH.

You can then use SSH from the command line with

```
ssh username@example.com
```